Blazor Server script references with versioning (cache busting)
Does Blazor Server offer any inbuilt ways of preventing old JavaScript files from being served by browser caches?
In an MVC project I would typically do the following:
<script src="js/global.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

This will instruct .NET to very neatly append a version hash to the src reference, which will ensure stale files do not get loaded by the browser cache. However it would appear that tag helpers are not supported in Blazor Server.
My question: Is there anything inbuilt into Blazor/.NET that will offer a similar result?
I'm aware of plenty of tricks to achieve the same thing manually, but I'd prefer to use the framework where possible.
